# How to group items in datagrid by username

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm working on wpf application which is populating datagrid with items from database.
That items represent user in coffe shop and how much money they made... here is an image of that :

[image]

- John
  Cash $ 192,00
- John Doe
  Cash $ 75,00
  Kart   75,00

Right now I'm populating my datagrid like this:

```
dtgCashAmount.ItemsSource = null;
dtgCashAmount.ItemsSource = BController.GetAllFinancialTransactionsByAllUsers(dateFrom, dateTo);
```

But I tried something like this (to group items acctually by username) - BUT IT DID NOT WORK :

First I added `Window.Resources` in my XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
         <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
     </Style>
```

After this I added this in my `datagrid`

```
<GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
    <GroupStyle.Panel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.Panel>
</GroupStyle>
```

And in my C# code I've tried something like this:

```
ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(DatabaseResults);
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Username"));
```

Basically I said: Okay group these results I get from database by Username to get an a result as I provided above in my question (below image).
But unfortunatelly I received following error :

> Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

Even if I checked that I'm not setting my datagrid source anywhere else..

**DataGrid XAML:**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" Name="dtgCashAmount " EnableRowVirtualization ="True" EnableColumnVirtualization = "True" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>

            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataGridCentering"/>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>

            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                </Style>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>  
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colPaymentType" Binding="{Binding PaymentType.Title }" Header="Payment type"  Foreground="Black"  FontSize="{x:Static local:Globals.dataGridfontSizeContent}" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colKorisnik" Binding="{Binding Username }" Header="Username"  Foreground="Black"  FontSize="{x:Static local:Globals.dataGridfontSizeContent}" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colPrice" Binding="{Binding TotalAmount}" Header="Total amount"  Foreground="Black"  FontSize="{x:Static local:Globals.dataGridfontSizeContent}" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

After **mm8** helped me it looks like this now:

[image]

I saw on internet example which is more nicer (for user Test it's nice organized):

[image]

mm8 mate is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: Post the XAML of your dtgCashAmount or whatever element that you are displaying the grouped items in. Did you put the GroupStyle in <DataGrid.GroupStyle>?

Comment: Do you want to show all data of one user in a single row or just next to each other? Change user "payment" fiels to list<Payment> with amount and type. so there is a field where a list of payments can be shown

Comment: @mm8 there it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GroupStyle` should be defined inside a `<DataGrid.GroupStyle>` element:

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
        <GroupStyle.Panel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.Panel>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

...and not as a direct child element of the `<DataGrid>` element.

Comment: This helped mate!! Thanks a lot! But please check for my edit I posted two images there on the bottom..